# no function clause matching in Plug controller

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, plug

My function does not match in the controller
My router:

```
scope "/api", AtmAppWeb do pipe_through :api
    get "/index", UserAtmController, :index
    get "/show", UserAtmController, :show
    get "/get_founds", UserAtmController, :get_founds
    post "/create", UserAtmController, :create
    put "/update", UserAtmController, :update
    delete "/delete", UserAtmController, :delete
end
```

My controller function:

```
def get_founds(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    user_atm = User.get_user_atm!(id)
    json put_status(conn, :ok), %{"message" => user_atm }
end
```

and this is my petition:

`GET /api/get_founds HTTP/1.1`

`Content-Type: application/json`

`Host: localhost:4000`

`Content-Length: 13`

`{`

`"id": "2"`

`}`

I don't know where is the error:

> Phoenix.ActionClauseError at GET /api/get_founds
> no function clause matching in AtmAppWeb.UserAtmController.get_founds/2

i expectted  that my function response a message with the atm_user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#module-routing), `Phoenix.Router.get/4` does not expect a payload as JSON, but rather it expects `id` to be a part of `path`.

That said, `GET /api/get_founds/2` would work as expected assuming the route would be `get "/get_founds/:id", UserAtmController, :get_founds`.